# I'm trying to make an infinite scrolling slider but the outcome is just a list

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When trying static data the slider works fine but when I get my data from an API the design breaks down into a list and the slider stops working.
The slider implementation is as follows:

js

```
 $(".feedback-slider").bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 177,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 6,
        slideMargin: 15,
        touchEnabled: false,
      });
```

React render

```
<ul className="feedback-slider">
                    {ApiRes.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <div className="feedback-single-box">
                            <div className="card p-20">
                                <p className="m-0">{item.review}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="media">
                                <div className="thumbnail">
                                    {
                                        item.customerimage === null ?
                                        <img 
                                            width="36px"
                                            src = "/assets/img/avtar.png"
                                            alt = "/"/>
                                        :
                                        <img
                                         width="36px"
                                         src={ImgPath + item.customerimage}
                                         alt={item.name}
                                         />   
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div className="media-body">
                                    <span className="designation">{item.name}</span>
                                    <h6 className="title">{item.title}</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    );
                    })}
                </ul>
```

The result I expected was an infinite scrolling slider but the outcome that i got was a list without the slider working at all. Could any one of you tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: From what I understand, you’re trying to create an infinite scroll list, but the tool you’re using is a slider (carousel). Those two things are completely different. But anyway, if you indeed want a slider, my guess is that you’re calling the bxSlider function before the content is rendered by React. You may need to use a useEffect hook or the componentDidMount lifecycle function, depending on what you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by **Mina**, when you execute the `bxSlider` function, there aren’t any items inside the `feedback-slider` list.

You need to use a [useEffect React Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) or the [componentDidMount lifecycle function](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) in order to wait for your API to return some data and React to render the list items. Only then you can initialize `bxSlider`.

Here is a code snippet that roughly reproduce what you want to achieve.

```js
// Function to generate fake API response
function getFakeAPIResponse() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(Array.from({ length:10 }).map((_, i) => [{
        review: `Review-${i}`,
        name: `Name-${i}`,
        title: `Title-${i}`
      }]))
    }, 1000)
  })
}

// Slider component
function Slider() {
  const [apiRes, setApiRes] = React.useState([])
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getFakeAPIResponse().then(setApiRes)
  }, [])
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (apiRes && apiRes.length > 0) {
      $(".feedback-slider").bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 177,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 6,
        slideMargin: 15,
        touchEnabled: false,
      })
    }
  }, [apiRes])
  
  return (
    <ul className="feedback-slider">
      {apiRes.map((item, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
          <div className="feedback-single-box">
            <div className="card p-20">
              <p className="m-0">{item.review}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="media">
              <div className="thumbnail">
                <img src='https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300' alt="/" />
              </div>
              <div className="media-body">
                <span className="designation">{item.name}</span>
                <h6 className="title">{item.title}</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

// Render React app
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#root'))

root.render(<Slider />)
```

```html
<!-- bxslider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- react -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<!-- app -->
<main id='root'></main>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because, at the time of executing the script of the slider, there are no elements inside the `feedback-slider` element, I suggest you execute the script after receiving the data.

Maybe you need to add the script in the `useEffect` hook and add the data and `refs` to the `li` elements as a dependency, so the script doesn't execute until the data reached out and the `li` elements are created and mounted.

Comment: Could you share a code snippet of what you are suggesting?